# Cancel a function in asp.net through javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a button that, when an user clicks on it and some fields are not correct, a message will be displayed. I would like to make that validation with javascript(or maybe someday I will), but I have no idea how to make that. Currently when the user clicks the button, the onclick function on the server side wont be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `<asp:Validator` tags; there are a number of different types of validators such as required field validators regex validators, etc.

They will validate the data both in client side code as well as server side code (unless you disable the client side check, which you can do).

This is *much* easier than manually validating the content in javascript and also manually validating it in server side code.

Technically though, to answer your question, when you have an `onclick` javascript handler for a submit button the return value, as a boolean, indicates whether or not the form should be submitted, so you just need to `return false` if the data is not valid to not submit the form.

```
<asp:Button Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return Validate();" />
<script type="text/Javascript">
    function Validate()
    {
        if(requiredFieldAIsMissing)  return false;

        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" Text="Click Me!" OnClick="myButton_OnClick" OnClientClick="javascript:confirm('Really?')" />
```

The [`OnClientClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) property emits the javascript (ahead of the javascript required to handle the postback), and if you return `false` from that event the rest of the event is cancelled and the postback will not fire.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like below would help you to understand.

HTML:

```
 <asp:textbox id="myText" runat="server" text="Hello" />
 <asp:button id="myButton" runat="server" text="Click Me" OnClick="Server_Event" />
```

ON Page_Load:

```
//Add onclick with return here
myButton.Attributes.Add("onclick","return ButtonClicked()");
```

Javascript:

```
function ButtonClicked(){
   var txt = document.getElementById("myText");
   if(txt.value != "Hello"){
      alert("It is not Hello, I am NOT posting back!");
      return false;
   } else {
      alert("It is Hello, I am posting back!");
      return true;
   }
}
```